# Variable in route by default working properly but not visible in URL it typed

Tags: symfony, url, routes

Thanks to my URL I can know what language and which article the user is looking for instance: article/id_aritlce/Title_of_article/**FR**

In case the user doesn't write the url with the language information I settle default value in the routing.yml file.

```
Site_Article:
path:     /article/{id}/{article_title}/{language}
defaults: {_controller: SiteBlogBundle:Blog:article, language: EN}
```

it is working just fine....
but if I type in the URL article/3/Titleofarticle/**EN**, then **EN** disapear from the URL. which is not what I want. (I still get the right page, which is with the EN language being display, but still would like to see it in the URL.)

Answer (score 2):

You can not provide default value for `en` locale and it always be in url when you type it.

But in this case to enable route `/article/{id}/{article_title}` without any locale you need to create one more route that will not have this parameter at all. In this case Symfony will choose locale based on your `fallback_locale` parameter that you set in `config.yml`

Your routing config must look like this:

```
Site_Article_With_Locale:
    path:     /article/{id}/{article_title}/{_locale}
    defaults: {_controller: SiteBlogBundle:Blog:article}

Site_Article:
    path:     /article/{id}/{article_title}
    defaults: {_controller: SiteBlogBundle:Blog:article}
```

Comment: my probleme is that when I type in the URL ==> **"article/id/article_title/EN"** then the URL is automatically rewrite and display ==> **"article/id/article_title"** (there are no mention of the EN, but I would like it to be displayed in the URL fact!)

Comment: And I solved your problem and post some working example.

Comment: Sorry but **I do not want to use local variable set in config.yml** for this exemple as this is a part of my site where the language is different from local variable

Comment: Ok. Rename `_locale` to `lang` and check it in your controller. If it is set then just use it with provided value. If it is null then set it in your desired place to your default value.